# How to save and work with data from input type radio

Tags: html, mysql, database, go

I'm going to do something like a test, and for this I would like to make a choice of the correct option when creating questions. I write data from radio to the database in the VARCHAR type, but I need to determine which input was selected in order to work with this data in the future. The data in the "correct" field is written as "on", which input was pressed is impossible to find out
html:

```
<form action="/save_test" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="wordOne"><input type="radio" name="correct"><br>
      <input type="text" name="wordTwo"><input type="radio" name="correct"><br>
      <input type="text" name="wordThree"><input type="radio" name="correct"><br>
      <input type="text" name="wordFour"><input type="radio" name="correct"><br>
      <button type="submit" name="button">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Go:

```
func save_test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  wordOne := r.FormValue("wordOne")
  wordTwo := r.FormValue("wordTwo")
  wordThree := r.FormValue("wordThree")
  wordFour := r.FormValue("wordFour")
  correct := r.FormValue("correct")

  //connecting
  db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(127.0.0.1:8889)/educ")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer db.Close()
  insert, error := db.Query(fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO `words` (`word1`, `word2`, `word3`, `word4`, `correct`) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", wordOne, wordTwo, wordThree, wordFour, correct))
  if error != nil {
    panic(error)
  }
  defer insert.Close()

  http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the html section

```
<form action="/save_test" method="post" id="questions_form">
  <input type="text" name="wordOne">
  <input type="text" name="wordTwo">
  <input type="text" name="wordThree">
  <input type="text" name="wordFour">
  <fieldset>
      <input type="radio" name="radio_answer">
      <input type="radio" name="radio_answer">
      <input type="radio" name="radio_answer">
      <input type="radio" name="radio_answer">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="hidden" name="correct">
  <button type="button" onclick="send()" name="button">Send</button>
</form>
<script>
    function send(){
        var form=document.getElementById("questions_form")
        var correct= form[9]
        for(var i=5;i<9;i++){
            if(form[i].checked){
                correct.value=i-4
            }
        }
        //No answer entered
        if(!correct.value){
            correct.value=0 //Default answer
        }
        form.submit()
    }
</script>
```

And in the golang section

```
insert, error := db.Query("INSERT INTO `words` (`word1`, `word2`, `word3`, `word4`, `correct`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", wordOne, wordTwo, wordThree, wordFour, correct)
```

Replace this section to prevent sql injection